# Yesod: content negotiation in POST request handlers

Tags: haskell, yesod

I want to have the same handler (route) for POST request with content type `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` and `application/json`. The first one is used for forms in hamlet templates and the second one is for json api.
Is it possible to define handler for both cases or it's better to create new route (and handler) for api requests?

Comment: Checking the request header in the handler should just work for your use case. Is there something you've tried that hasn't worked?

Comment: @MichaelSnoyman should I parse header manually or I can use some existing functions like `selectRep`?

Comment: The function [acceptsJson](http://www.stackage.org/haddock/lts-2.11/yesod-core-1.4.9.1/Yesod-Core-Json.html#v:acceptsJson) may be what you're looking for.

Comment: @MichaelSnoyman doc says it's based on `Accept` header. not `Content-Type`

Comment: Sorry, my mistake, you're correct. That's not relevant. Looks like you'll just need to inspect `content-type` directly.